# Mysql search query with php

Tags: php, html, mysql

I need to do a mysql query that will search (in columns) `nome` and `cognome` (in the `Prenotazioni` table).

The problem is: the query must search name and surname or surname and name (they can also be 3 or 4 values) and I have only 1 search form. If I have two john with different surnames (black and white), and i put in search form john black or white john, The query will give me both results

How i can fix it?

index.php

```
<table border="10">
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><b>CERCA</b></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="./cerca.php">
        <tr>
          <td>Cerca:</td>
            <td width="250" align="left"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" size="70" name="ricerca"/>
          </td>
        </tr>                   
        <tr>
          <td></td>
    <td align="left"><input style="width:100px;" type="submit" value="Cerca"/>
        </tr>
        </form>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

cerca.php

```
 <!doctype html><html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Ricerca</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php

include('./config.php');

$name = isset($_POST['ricerca']) ? preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($_POST['ricerca'])) : '';

if ($name != '') {
    $q = 'SELECT * FROM Prenotazioni WHERE 1=2';
    $parts = explode(' ', $name);

    foreach ($parts as $part) {
        $q .= ' OR nome LIKE \'%' . $part . '\' OR cognome LIKE \'%' . $part . '\'';
    }

    $exec = mysql_query($q);
    if (mysql_num_rows($exec)) {
        echo '<tr>
                <td width="242">
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Nome</strong></td>
                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Cognome</strong></td>
                        </tr>';

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)) {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">' . $row['nome'] . '</td>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">' . $row['cognome'] . '</td>                     <p><br>
                   <br>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Errore: nessuna corrispondenza trovata.';
    }

}
else {
    echo 'Errore: Inserisci un nome.';
}
?>
```

Comment: `%$part` will only search at the end of the name. It probably should be `%$part%`.

Comment: no now it work...i'm wrong isset($_POST['name'])...right is isset($_POST['ricerca'])... but now i have an other problem

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**EDIT**
GOOD CODE:

```
$name = isset($_POST['ricerca']) ? preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($_POST['ricerca'])) : '';

if ($name != '') {
$parts = explode(" ",$name);

$count = count($parts);

$q = "SELECT * FROM Prenotazioni WHERE";                     

for($i = 0;$i < $count;$i++)
{
    if($i != $count-1)
        $q = $q.
        " (nome LIKE '%".$parts[$i]."%' OR
          cognome LIKE '%".$parts[$i]."%') AND ";
    else
        $q = $q.
        " (nome LIKE '%".$parts[$i]."%' OR
          cognome LIKE '%".$parts[$i]."%')";
}
$exec = mysql_query($q);
    if (mysql_num_rows($exec)) {
        echo '<tr>
                    <table border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#CCCCCC">
                        <tr></tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Nome</strong></td>
                            <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><strong>Cognome</strong></td>
                        </tr>';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec)) {
            echo '<tr>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">' . $row['nome'] . '</td>
                    <td align="center" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">' . $row['cognome'] . '</td>';
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Errore: nessuna corrispondenza trovata.';
    }

}
else {
    echo 'Errore: Inserisci un nome.';
}
```

Comment: Sorry about the errro. I have editted and tested the answer please replace  `'%'.$parts[$i].'%'` with `'%".$parts[$i]."%'`. I made a mistake in using single quotes

Answer (score 1):

I faced this same challenge 3days ago and this resolved it: modify line 6-11 of cerca.php to this

```
$parts = explode(" ",$name);

$count = count($parts);

$q = "SELECT * FROM Prenotazioni WHERE";                     

for($i = 0;$i < $count;$i++)
{
    if($i != $count-1)
        $q = $q.
        " (nome LIKE '%".$parts[$i]."%' OR
          cognome LIKE '%".$parts[$i]."%') AND ";
    else
        $q = $q.
        " (nome LIKE '%".$parts[$i]."%' OR
          cognome LIKE '%".$parts[$i]."%')";
}
$exec = mysql_query($q);
```

Given "**john black**","**black john**" and "**bla joh**" return the SAME RESULTS and "white john" isn't the same as "black john".  I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

make mysql query string using above mu code and run this query and make row according to you

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM Prenotazioni WHERE";                     

for($i = 0;$i < $count;$i++)
{
    if($i) {
        $q .= ' and ';
    }
    $q = $q . " (concat(nome, ' ', cognome) LIKE '%'.$parts[$i].'%')";
}
```

Comment: make mysql query string using above mu code and run this query and make   row according to you